# How to display the status of the user?

Tags: 8, theming, users

I created a TWIG template for the "Teaser" view of the user account.

I want to display a logo and change its color according to the status of the user :

- When the user is logged in `<i class="user-online fa fa-circle fa-lg"></i> Online`
- When the user is logged in and the last access is less than 30 minutes `<i class="user-absent fa fa-circle fa-lg"></i> Absent`
- When the user is offline `<i class="user-offline fa fa-circle fa-lg"></i> Offline`

How to display the status of the user ?

I think it must be possible to create conditions in TWIG

Answer (score 2):

you can use [template_preprocess_user](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.module/function/template_preprocess_user/8.2.x)  like

```
 /**
 * Implements hook_entity_presave().
 */
function mytemplate_preprocess_user(&$variables) {
  // get user object
  $user = $variables['elements']['#user'];
  //- The user has logged in at least once
  if ($user->getLastLoginTime()) {
    if (account_is_logged_in_less_then_thirty_minutes($user->id())) {
      $status = 'Online';
    }
    else {
      $status = 'Absent';
    }
  }
  else {
    $status = 'offline';
  }
  $variables['status'] = $status;
}

/**
 * @param $uid
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function account_is_logged_in_less_then_thirty_minutes($uid) {
  $connection = Database::getConnection();
  $query = $connection->select('sessions', 'sessions')
    ->fields('sessions', ['sid', 'uid', 'timestamp'])
    ->condition('sessions.uid', $uid, '=')
    //- chef if the user was online in 30 minutes (60 * 30)
    ->condition('sessions.timestamp', \Drupal::time()
        ->getRequestTime() - (60 * 30), '>')
    ->execute();
  //- Get result.
  $results = $query->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
  return (count($results) > 0) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

In you template check on `status` variable like the following:

```
{% if status == 'Online' %}
  <i class="user-online fa fa-circle fa-lg"></i> Online
{% elseif status == 'Absent' %}
  <i class="user-absent fa fa-circle fa-lg"></i> Absent
{% else %}
  <i class="user-offline fa fa-circle fa-lg"></i> Offline
{% endif %}
```

Add `use Drupal\Core\Database\Database;` to the top of your file.

Comment: I found another question, but I do not want to use views https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/241342/show-if-a-user-is-logged-in-or-not

Comment: This person deleted their account or comments and it’s confusing to follow.

Comment: yeah i think, i edit my answer because, the same person with another account post this question again

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53603276/how-to-view-a-users-status-online-absent-offline There is another problem with this code. Now offline users are marked as absent